# Tomcat SSL certificate configuration : java.lang.Exception, Public keys in reply and keystore don't match

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, keytool, tomcat9

I want to configure SSL in my apache Tomcat. Here are the steps are followed :
Step1 Create a private key:

```
keytool -keysize 2048 -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore tomcat.keystore
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore tomcat.keystore -destkeystore tomcat.keystore -deststoretype pkcs12
```

Step2 Create a CSR:

```
keytool -certreq -keyalg RSA -alias tomcat -file myFQDN.csr -keystore tomcat.keystore
```

After Step 2, the CSR is sent to PKI authority for certificate generation (Globasign in my case).

Step 3 Install the root certificate from Globalsign

```
keytool -import -alias root -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file gdig2.crt
```

Step4 Install the intermediate certificate from Globalsign

```
keytool -import -alias intermed -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
```

Step 5 Install the certificate

```
keytool -import -alias tomcat -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file certificate.crt
```

Step 5 produces an error :
**keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Public keys in reply and keystore don't match** 
But when I change the alias for certificate, it imports well. But since the private key and certificate do not have the same alias, ssl configuration do not work.

Help please.

Comment: How did the CA reply to the CSR? PKCS#7 format or just the signed certificate? And how did you get the root and the intermediate certificates?

Comment: @always_a_rookie_to_learn tjey sent a .PEM file. I copied the content of the file in another file and saved with .crt extension.  I dowloaded the root certificate and intermediate certificate from their website, on a link they provided.